# How should I analyse my ordinal data when there is a between-groups design?

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, ordinal-data, likert

I have asked listeners to rate some voices on 10 different questions. There were 2 groups of listeners. Group 1 had Set A of questions whereas Group 2 had Set B. Listeners responded on a Likert scale from 1-7, where each end of the scale was labelled (Strongly disagree 1, strongly agree 7). As such, I'm treating the response variable as ordinal. I want to run a mixed effects model in RStudio with the following fixed effects:

- Participant age group (ordinal)
- Participant gender (nominal)
- Participant location (nominal)
- Participant familiarity with accent (ordinal)
- Stimulus accent (nominal)
- Question (nominal)

Additionally, I would like to model the following:

- An interaction effect between stimulus accent and question
- A random effect of participant.

So far I've run a mixed-effects ordinal regression model on separate datasets of listener group 1 and listener group 2 (with some difficulty, as some variables violated the assumption of proportional odds). I still have the following questions:

1. If I want to analyze all the questions in the same model, is it best practice to z-score participant responses?
2. If so, I would then need to run a linear model, rather than ordinal. Would this help me with my proportional odds issue?

Answer (score 0):

Since the dependent variable for each question is ordinal, if you want to model each one separately you should use ordinal regression to start. But, when the proportional odds assumption is violated there are at least two options. First, you could try a multinomial logistic. Second, you could try partial proportional odds model.

There is no reason to z-score your dependent variable and doing so doesn't really make it less ordinal or make a linear model more appropriate. If you z score the integers from 1 to 7, you will get 7 distinct values, which won't be integers, but still will be ordinal. There's nothing about "ordinal" that requires the responses to be integers. Indeed, the definition of "ordinal" means that you can change the numbers to anything you like, as long as order is preserved. E.g. instead of 1 to 7 you could use 0.24, 12, 31, 93, 122, 2011, and 49492222.